# Possible problem with references when solving inverting a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I was trying to find a solution for inverting a binary tree using iteration, but it seems that this solution doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't work? I know there are different solutions, but this was my first one and I feel like it should work.  My initial idea is that I want to pop two child nodes every iteration and swap those because they are two sibling nodes until I have swapped every node in the tree. I feel like it has something to do with references because the output is just the original tree. My guess is that the stack is just storing copies of the nodes so it's doing the swapping, but it's not actually swapping anything in the original tree. If that's the case, how would I fix that? I know that maybe in c++ we could use reference types or something like that, but how does can I do that in java?

Thank you!

```
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) return root;
        Stack<TreeNode> s = new Stack<>();
        s.push(root.left);
        s.push(root.right);
        
        while (!s.empty()) {
             TreeNode nd1 = s.pop();
             TreeNode nd2 = s.pop();
             TreeNode temp = nd1;
             nd1 = nd2;
             nd2 = temp;
             if (nd1 != null && nd2 != null) {
                 s.push(nd1.left);
                 s.push(nd1.right);
                 s.push(nd2.left);
                 s.push(nd2.right);
             } else if (nd1 == null && nd2 != null) {
                 s.push(nd2.left);
                 s.push(nd2.right);
             } else if (nd2 == null && nd1 != null) {
                 s.push(nd1.left);
                 s.push(nd1.right);
             }
        }
        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can not swap leaf node just swap two reference. Even in C++, you should operate with parent node.

Comment: But how come? If we have a reference that points to the left node and a reference pointing to the right node, wouldn't swapping those values mean that we are swapping the actual nodes? If it doesn't, then does that mean anything stored on the stack is just a copy?

Comment: your mistake is `nd1 = nd2; nd2 = temp;` does not affect the parent node

Comment: So does that mean that nd1 and nd2 aren't actually references to the parent node's left and right child? Because my initial thought was that if I pushed the left and right child to the stack, those two nodes were be the actual parents children; so for example, I could do nd1.val = 4 and nd2.val = 5 and that would change the actual values inside the original tree. In this example, i thought that doing nd1= nd2; nd2=temp would swap those two nodes. But obviously, that's not the case. So why doesn't the swap work?

Comment: basically: `root.left` holds a reference to `left node object`, doing `TreeNode left = root.left` you are getting another reference to `left node object`, that new reference has nothing in common with `root.left` except they both reference to the same object, there is no option to swap addresses of pointers that the pointers are pointing to in Java, like it is possible in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

We can invert tree level by level.

```java
public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.offer(root);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode node = queue.poll();
        TreeNode temp = node.left;
        node.left = node.right;
        node.right = temp;
        if (node.left != null) {
            queue.offer(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            queue.offer(node.right);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! That was my other solution, but I was wondering what was wrong with my original solution. Do you know why my solution wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive recursive solution is:

```java
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        if (root != null) {
            TreeNode r = root.right;
            root.right = root.left;
            root.left = r;
            invertTree(root.left);
            invertTree(root.right);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Now we would like to avoid recursion, and at first glance we need to do exactly the same - swap left and right and put them into a stack, below is top-down solution:

```java
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        Deque<TreeNode> stack = new LinkedList<>();
        stack.add(root);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNode node = stack.pollFirst();
            if (node != null) {
                TreeNode r = node.right;
                node.right = node.left;
                node.left = r;
                stack.addFirst(node.right);
                stack.addFirst(node.left);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

if we would like to implement bottom-up solution it would be:

```java
    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        Deque<TreeNode> stack = new LinkedList<>();
        TreeNode current = root;
        while (!stack.isEmpty() || current != null) {
            while (current != null) {
                stack.addFirst(current);
                current = current.left;
            }
            TreeNode pop = stack.pollFirst();
            current = pop.right;
            TreeNode tmp = pop.left;
            pop.left = pop.right;
            pop.right = tmp;
        }
        return root;
    }
```